# Proving in the certain ring that an element is invertible iff it is right quasi-regular

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Define an element $\ a $ in ring$\ R $ to be regular if there exists an element $\ b \in  R $ such that $\ aba=a $.

Element $\ a $ in ring$\ R $ is right quasi-regular if there exists an element $\ b \in  R $ such that $\ a+b-ab=0 $. The notion of the left quasi-regular element is defined accordingly. We call an element of the ring quasi-regular if it is right quasi-regular and left quasi-regular.

Let$\ R $ be a ring with unity such that each regular element different from 1 is quasi-regular.

I would like to show that if $\ 0, 1 \neq a \in R $ is invertible if and only if $\ a $ is right quasi-regular.

I have already shown that $\ a $ is invertible if and only if$\ a $ is regular, but I don't know how to proceed. I can also show that if $\ a $ is right quasi-regular, then it is also left quasi-regular. If I could show that quasi regularity of $\ a $ implies regularity of $\ a $, the theorem would follow.

I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: What is quasi regular?

Comment: I have specified this above. Thank you